# Yii Bootstrap Navbar .active not applying on some pages

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have a Yii project, where I user yii-bootsrtap. I have some static pages (like FAQ and About page) that the user can access from the NavBar. It looks like this:

```
Index | About us | FAQ | Login ...
```

My problem is, the .active class is not applying to the menubar item, when I navigate to a static page. It works well on other pages, like Index and Login.

I am using my own action to render these static pages:

```
// in SiteController.php: 

public function actionStatic($view)
{
    $this->render('static/' . $view);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `CMenu` to show your menu, adding an `active` key to the actual menu item may resolve your problem.

If you add the below to your specific menu item, it will show active if the controller action you're on is 'blog':

```
'active'=>(Yii::app()->controller->action->id=='blog')
```

The full snippet would look something like this:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
    'items' => array(
        'label'=>'Blog',
        'active'=>(Yii::app()->controller->action->id=='blog')
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the default CMenu "active" property to work, you have to make sure that each item  in the menu's url matches the exact url that you're going to (in this case, static/viewname).

See here for how active property is resolved:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/zii/widgets/CMenu.php#L306

Comment: I checked, and they are. I have one, called Gallery (pointing: site.com/gallery) and when I click it, the URL is the same as the link's href.
This is still a problem is some of the sites, but I couldn't find any difference between the working and not working sites. :\

Comment: I found 1 difference, but this shouldn't be the problem. I use yii-bootstraps TbNavbar widget for the main menu, and I when I add a menuItem with `'url' => array('/user/statistics')` than it works. But when I use `'url' => array('/user/profile/id'.Yii::app()->user->id)`, then it's not working. I replaced Controller's `createUrl` in one place and it solved there, but not with the profile menuItem. It's really confusing...

Comment: But in the HTML at the client side have the right href value.

Comment: If that is an exact copy/paste, it seems that the url for profile will be invalid, as it is missing a trailing '/' after id.  Also, I would expect the url to be created using the route/parameter method: 'url' => array('/user/profile', array('id' => Yii::app()->user->id))  FWIW, I have seen this problem pop up numerous times and it is always a small silly thing keeping it from performing as expected.

Comment: i know this is a relatively old post, probably resolved already for the OP, but for the sake of completeness, @PrplHaz4, I think you're wrong in stating "you have to make sure that each item in the menu's url matches the exact url that you're going to". The only thing you actually need to do is to setup an 'active' key for the specific menu and give it a value of whatever condition you like, ie. `'active'=>(Yii::app()->controller->action->id=='blog')`